# prevent python from escaping quotes in sql queries

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, postgis

I am using postgres database with postgis extension. I have to insert into data into postgres using python as backend. I am using psycopg2 for connectivity and version of my python is 3.7 . I am not able to push my data because python keeps on escaping string literals. The following is my code.

```
def insert(lvalues):
    lvalues = [str(i) for i in lvalues]
    values = ', '.join(lvalues)
    return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cursor, conn = connect()
    cord = [
        [
            [
                67.774658203125,
                25.69103802005013
            ],
            [
                68.90625,
                24.367113562651262
            ],
            [
                73.970947265625,
                25.958044673317843
            ],
            [
                74.87182617187499,
                28.565225490654658
            ],
            [
                70.33447265624999,
                28.815799886487298
            ],
            [
                67.774658203125,
                25.69103802005013
            ]
        ]
    ]
    js = insert(('GISid', 'srid', 'familyid', 'geom', 'nameofgeom'))
    jst = '''{  "type": "Polygon","coordinates": ''' + str(cord) + ''',
                      "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}
            }'''


    print(cursor.mogrify(
        "INSERT INTO public.spatial_data(gid, srid, familyid, geom, nameofgeom) VALUES (103,4326,2,ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s),'polygon') ",
        (jst,)))
```

I result i get is this as below:

```
b'INSERT INTO public.spatial_data(gid, srid, familyid, geom, nameofgeom) VALUES (103,4326,2,ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{  "type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[67.774658203125, 25.69103802005013], [68.90625, 24.367113562651262], [73.970947265625, 25.958044673317843], [74.87182617187499, 28.565225490654658], [70.33447265624999, 28.815799886487298], [67.774658203125, 25.69103802005013]]],\n        "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}\n            }\'),\'polygon\') '
```

Can somebody suggest a way of removing \ and \n that appear in the mogrify result. cursor is psycopg2 connection cursor object.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though mogrify gives a statement that will be similar to the one that would get executed if you use execute command, it gives us a repr version. If plan on using mogrify output directly there should be a problem, but if you use an separate execute statement it **might** result in error.( Not always necessarily). String replacing helped me escape the problem.

```
jst.replace('\n', ' ').replace("\'",' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use `cursor.execute` rather than `.mogrify`? It sounds like it's already doing the right thing...

- The backslashes in any case come from the `print` statement and wouldn't be sent to the database.
- If you do need to get rid of the newlines, they all come from the `jst` variable; use something like: `jst.replace('\n', ' ')`

Comment: cursor.mogrify gives the exact code that would be inserted or passed to execute function. Even in docs they have used print statements and no such issue is seen. I implemented ur suggestions the program ran but the query didn't insert anything inside the table.

Comment: The fact that the output of the `print` starts with `b'` means that it's printing the `repr` form of the value (which is a bytes, not a string); if you want to see the text of the query, you'll have to decode it back to a string for printing. As for the query not inserting anything - can you check the return value, it may give you the count of rows inserted? Are you in a transaction, so it gets rolled back when you exit the program without committing?

Comment: It wasn't committing as repr form is rejected by database but no error is shown. if you edit ur ans to include the second comment, i will accept it as answer @sabik

Comment: You aren't meant to send the output of the `print` to the database, though, you're meant to use `cursor.execute`?